# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [hash size=20000]

Tags: packages

I'm using a lot of packages right now:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ctable}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

%subfigures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%inline lists
\usepackage{paralist}
```

So, this error started to appear when I started to \usepackage{pgfplots}.  Changing the order changes the details of the error message (it chokes on loading a different library), Without removing any of the packages, how can I get this to work?

> If you really absolutely need more capacity,
> you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

Where can I find a wizard?

Comment: Do you get the error just from loading the packages? Or form actually using them?

Comment: Merely loading!

Comment: Do you have mathematics in the section (or the like) heading?

Comment: Usually just running with `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex` should help.

Comment: It might be helpful to post a log here: for example, which TeX system do you use? I have no issues with your preamble and pdfLaTeX from TL2012.

Comment: TeX Live sets the hash size to 215000. I get the error after trying to define 213470 control sequences, which should be more than sufficient for a wide number of documents. Please, in cases like this, always specify your TeX distribution. I'd say that the setting made by BaKoMa TeX is simply wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed it.

In the latex configuration file, I just increased `hash_extra` and then `pool_size` by a factor of 10:

```
hash_extra=100000
pool_size=5000000
```

If I'm not mistaken, these are in *bytes*, so 5 MB for a pool is very reasonable.  If I encounter any more errors, I'll likely make `pool_size` 50MB.

For bakoma tex, the configuration file is called `texmf.ini` in the root install directory.